# How to sort map of object on the basis of date

Tags: java, sorting, linkedhashmap

How to sort map on the basis of time field in object. My Map looks like:

`Map<Integer, ShiftDTO> -> ShiftDTO` consist of following key: `shiftName`, `shiftStartTime`, `shiftEndTime`. `shiftStartTime` is of type `Date`, and I want to sort on the basis of date in ascending order. Following code I was using to sort on the basis of map key:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, ShiftDTO> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ShiftDTO>();
    v.getShiftHashMap().entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
```

But how can I sort all shift entries on the basis of `shiftStartTime`?

Comment: You could use a `TreeMap` for sorting it. Any reason you are using a `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: just to maintain the order of insertion

Comment: How can you maintain insertion order and also sort it?

Comment: your point is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the comparator in the `sorted` method. You can use the following comparator:

```
(entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue().shiftStartTime.compareTo(entry2.getValue().shiftStartTime)
```

Or else you can use a `TreeMap` and pass this comparator to its constructor while creating the map.